# received-im-msg signal message

Tags: c, signals, instant-messaging, libpurple

I want to make a program that logs in few IDs on different protocols, receives the messages and gives answers to different messages (commands).

example:

**me:** who
**bot:** I'm a libpurple powered bot.

The code looks like this:

```
static void received_im_msg(PurpleAccount *account, char *sender, char *message,
                              PurpleConversation *conv, PurpleMessageFlags flags)
{
    if (conv==NULL) {
        conv = purple_conversation_new(PURPLE_CONV_TYPE_IM, account, sender);
    }

    printf("%s: %s\n", sender, message);

    char *answer;

    if (message == "who") {
        answer="I'm a libpurple powered bot.";
    } else if (message=="hello") {
        answer="Hello, my firend!";
    } else {
        answer="Unknown command.";
    }
    //print the answer, so we can see it in terminal:
    printf("bot: %s\n",message);  

    //send the message:
    purple_conv_im_send(purple_conversation_get_im_data(conv),answer);
}
```

For me, this code looks just OK, but doesn't work as expected. Any message the bot receives, the answer will be always **Unknown command.**. I can't understand why the

```
message == "who"
```

is not true, even if

```
printf("%s: %s\n", sender, message);
```

prints something like:
**example_id_345: who**.

Do you have any idea of why this thing happens? What I did wrong?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`strcmp`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) function:

```
if (strcmp(message, "who") == 0) {
    answer="I'm a libpurple powered bot.";
} else if (strcmp(message, "hello") == 0) {
```

`==` checks that the pointers hold the same address, which is not what you want.